# SQL: performing a calculation and ensuring the first record of each id is a null value

Tags: sql, sql-server, gps

I am using SQL Server 2012. I have a very large database containing over 40 million records for GPS tracks for mail delivery. I was able to calculate the time difference for each record by using the following query:

```
UPDATE a SET SecSince=
  DATEDIFF(SECOND, (SELECT TOP 1 [DateTime]
                 FROM [dbo].[Database]
                 WHERE
                     COMPANY=a.COMPANY
                     AND CarrierID=a.CarrierID
                     AND  [DateTime]< a.[DateTime]
                 ORDER BY [DateTime] DESC)
              , a.[DateTime])
FROM [dbo].[Database] a
WHERE 0 < (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [dbo].[Database]
           WHERE
               Company=a.Company
               AND CarrierID=a.CarrierID
               AND [DateTime] < a.[DateTime])
```

the result is the following:

```
Company CarrierID   SecSince    
    A   1           NULL     
    A   1           800    
    A   1           900    
    B   1           NULL       
    B   1           876    
    B   1           904    
    B   2           NULL       
    B   2           122    
    B   2           177
```

The first record of each new carrierid and company is a NULL value - which is exactly what I want.

Here's where I am having difficulties. I want to run the same query, but this time I want to calculate GPS distance. I am able to calculate the Haversine distance using this formula:

```
UPDATE A
set A.[Haversine] = 
6371000* 2 * ASIN ( SQRT (POWER(SIN((A.Latitude - B.Latitude)*pi()/180 / 2),2) + COS(A.Latitude * pi()/180) * COS(B.Latitude *pi()/180) * POWER(SIN((A.Longitude - B.Longitude) *pi()/180 / 2), 2) ) )
from [dbo].[Database] A INNER JOIN [dbo].[Database] B ON B.ID = (A.ID + 1)
WHERE A.[Trip] = A.[Trip]
```

This works fine in terms of distance calculation. Except now I want a NULL value for the first record of each new CarrierID and Company combination record (or Trip) just like in the SecSince calculation.

I have tried reworking the SecSince query so that it runs the distance calculation but I can't seem to get the syntax right. I guess the issue is with the nested select top 1. I was hoping someone could tell me what I'm doing wrong and help me with the correct syntax.

```
UPDATE A
set A.[Haversine] = 
6371000* 2 * ASIN ( SQRT (POWER(SIN((A.Latitude - B.Latitude)*pi()/180 / 2),2) + COS(A.Latitude * pi()/180) * COS(B.Latitude *pi()/180) * POWER(SIN((A.Longitude - B.Longitude) *pi()/180 / 2), 2) ) )
(SELECT TOP 1 [DateTime]
        FROM [dbo].[Database]
                 WHERE
                     COMPANY=a.COMPANY
                     AND CarrierID=a.CarrierID
                     AND  [DateTime]< a.[DateTime]
                 ORDER BY [DateTime] DESC)
              , a.[DateTime])
from [dbo].[Emerson] A INNER JOIN [dbo].[Database] B ON B.ID = (A.ID + 1)
WHERE A.[Trip] = A.[Trip]
FROM [dbo].[Database] a
WHERE 0 < (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [dbo].[Database]
           WHERE
               Company=a.Company
               AND CarrierID=a.CarrierID
               AND [DateTime] < a.[DateTime])
```

this is the result I want:

```
Trip Company CarrierID Latitude Longitude ID    DateTime           SecSince Haversine DESIRED
    3   7002    1   50.06417    -96.46426   1   15/02/2013 14:40:38 NULL    6.05    NULL
    3   7002    1   50.06421    -96.4643    2   15/02/2013 14:55:37 899     0.00    6.05
    3   7002    1   50.06421    -96.4643    3   15/02/2013 15:08:46 789     16.61   0.00
    4   7003    1   50.06435    -96.46421   4   15/02/2013 15:21:06 NULL    0.00    NULL
    4   7003    1   50.06435    -96.46421   5   15/02/2013 15:22:16 70      0.00    0.00
    4   7003    1   50.06435    -96.46421   6   15/02/2013 15:23:06 50      0.00    0.00
    5   7002    3   50.06435    -96.46421   7   15/02/2013 15:32:51 NULL    0.00    NULL
    5   7002    3   50.06435    -96.46421   8   15/02/2013 15:33:01 10      5.51    0.00
    5   7002    3   50.0644     -96.46421   9   15/02/2013 15:38:30 329     5.51    5.51
    5   7002    3   50.06435    -96.46421   10  15/02/2013 15:45:04 394     0.00    5.51
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have SQL server 2012 at your disposal you should use the cool new functions, like `LAG` in this case.

```
with cte as
(
  select 
    id,
    lag([datetime],1) over(partition by trip order by id) as prev_datetime,
    lag([latitude],1) over(partition by trip order by id) as prev_latitude,
    lag([longitude],1) over(partition by trip order by id) as prev_longitude
  from 
    data
)
update data
set
  secsince = DATEDIFF(SECOND, prev_datetime, [datetime]),
  haversine = 6371000* 2 * ASIN ( SQRT (POWER(SIN((Latitude - prev_Latitude)*pi()/180 / 2),2) + COS(Latitude * pi()/180) * COS(prev_Latitude *pi()/180) * POWER(SIN((Longitude - prev_Longitude) *pi()/180 / 2), 2) ) )
from 
  data
  inner join cte on cte.id = data.id
```

Check out the [SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e2e20/1/1).

Comment: Thank you so much. This was exactly what I was looking for and it only took 5 minutes for the query to run. It worked perfectly and is a lot more efficient than what I was previously doing.